# Chart JS Fill Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I have configured a simple line chart using chartJS. I noticed that when the graph has steep values the fill of the chart has issues filling the entire graph. Is this due to it being curved and if so, is there documentation on how to fix it?

Below is my code and a screenshot-

```
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 350);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(74, 222, 222, 0.8)');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(74, 222, 222, 0.5)');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(120, 127, 246, 0.2)');

  const data = {
    labels: {{reputationDateArray | tojson}},
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Reputation Over Time',
      backgroundColor: gradient,
      borderColor: 'rgba(74, 222, 222, 0.9)',
      fill: true,
          data:  {{reputationArray}},
    }]
  };

  const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {}
  };
 const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
```

Current Fill Appearance[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue3i7.png)

Comment: This does seem weird. Does it happen if you use a simpler gradient e.g. red, red or a simple non-gradient single color? Could you make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/298a0v1y/) derived from your code and screenshort using the current Chart.js (3.9.1) doesn't replicate the issue.